# What does the designation "SGL" mean for a SAS Host Bus Adapter?

Tags: sas, hba

We're looking for a non-RAID SAS Host Bus Adapter to connect a tape drive to our Dell PowerEdge server. Shopping around online for an LSI 9300-8e we see models listed as just "9300-8e" and models listed as "9300-8e SGL".

What's the SGL stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/Host%20Bus%20Adapters/LSI_12Gb_SAS_FAQ_9300_Family.pdf) I imagine it is an abbreviation for `single`

> What is the difference between a “Single” and “Kit” package?
>
> In addition to the “Single” package, some models are available in “Kits” which include compatible cables for connection to the internal ports of
>   SAS 9300 HBAs. “Kits” only exist for ...